# Selenium finds only a fraction of href links

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get all the products' url from [this](https://www.ocado.com/browse/fresh-20002) webpage, but I managed to get only a fraction of it.

My first attempt was to **scrape** the webpage with Beautifulsoup, but then I realized selenium would be better as I needed to click the "Show more" button several times. I also added a code to scroll down the page as I though that was the problem, but the result didn't change.

```
import time   
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
def getListingLinks(link):
    # Open the driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(3)
    # scroll down: repeated to ensure it reaches the bottom and all items are loaded
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    
    listing_links = []  
    
    while True:
        try:
            driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/button'))))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main-content > div:nth-child(2) > div.main-column > div.btn-wrapper.center > button"))))
            print("Button clicked")
            links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('fop-contentWrapper')
            for link in links:
                algo=link.find_element_by_css_selector('.fop-contentWrapper a').get_attribute('href')
                print(algo)
                listing_links.append(str(algo))
        except:
            print("No more Buttons")
            break
    
    driver.close()
    return listing_links 

fresh_food = getListingLinks("https://www.ocado.com/browse/fresh-20002")

print(len(fresh_food))  ## Output: 228
```

As you can see, I get 228 urls while I would like to get 5605 links, that is the actual number of products in the webpage according to Ocado. I believe I have a problem with the order of my code, but can't find the proper order. I would sincerely appreciate any help.